# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.TreeMap field

Tags: java, spring-boot, treemap

I have a Points Object with a property of Map<Round, Integer>. Everything worked fine! I then decided to swap this for a TreeMap so that all Points records were sorted by the Round key. Implemented Round with Comparable Interface as part of this. I'm getting an Illegal Argument Exception error:

```
Can not set java.util.TreeMap field to org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentSortedMap
```

I can't see what the issue is - any clues?

Field:

```
private TreeMap<Round, Integer> points;
```

Constructor:

```
this.points = new TreeMap<>();
```

Setter:

```
public void setPoints(TreeMap<Round, Integer> points) {
  this.points = points;
}
```

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]?

Comment: "I can't see what the issue is" meaning you don't see why you cannot cast a PersistentSortedMap into a TreeMap or meaning why is someone trying to set my TreeMap with a PersistentSortedMap?

Comment: At the time, I couldn't understand what hibernate needed to deal with a TreeMap, my newbie assumption being that TreeMap was a common data structure. I did notice hibernate converting it to a PersitstentSortedMap but didn't really understand what argument it was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [collections-semantics](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-semantics)

> The semantics of a collection describes how to handle the collection, including
> -the collection subtype to use - java.util.List, java.util.Set, java.util.SortedSet, etc.

> SORTED_MAP
> A map that is sorted by keys according to a Comparator defined on its mapping

> By default, Hibernate interprets the defined type of the plural attribute and makes an interpretation as to which classification it fits in to, using the following checks:
> ...
> if a SortedMap → SORTED_MAP

You should use interface `Map`(if sorting doesn't matter)/[`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedMap.html) instead of implementation `TreeMap` when defining your field.

i.e.

```java
private SortedMap<Round, Integer> points;

public void setPoints(SortedMap<Round, Integer> points) {
  this.points = points;
}

public SortedMap getPoints() {
  return this.points;
}
```

Comment: I've just solved this and now seen your answer. That is correct! Hibernate does not understand what to do with TreeMap. I also used @SortNatural for the annotation of the SortedMap. Lesson learned. Thanks so much for replying.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like a it's an hibernate issue, first try to add those annotations on your map field

```
@CollectionTable(name = "attributes_tags" ,joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "swift_configuration_id" )  )
@MapKeyColumn(name = "attribute_name" )
@Column(name = "attribute_tag")
private TreeMap<String, String> attributesTags = new HashMap <> (); // used to map the attributes name with their tags
```

in this case hibernate will stock the fields in they're natural order in the data base but when you retrive the data it wil be sorted (depending on the implemented Comparable)

Comment: I'm seeing an error on trying to initiate a TreeMap as a HashMap. Although I do agree I could use Map/HashMap on the Constructor and create a TreeMap (sorted) from it in the Application.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close the loop. Either use SortedMap as per samabcde answer. Alternatively, if retaining the Map Interface, use @SortNatural as the annotation. They do not need used together.

```
@SortNatural
private Map<Round, Integer> points;
```